# How to stop robocopy from exiting the build?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using Gitlab 8.15.4 and the latest runner for that build.  Because of our firewall I can't run npm install so I'm copying the node-modules from another location into the build folder.  The runner is on a Windows 7 machine.

My first attempt:
(.gitlab-ci.yml)

```
before_script:
- robocopy S:\Storage\GitLab-Runner\Assets\node_modules .\node_modules /s
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo starting
    - gulp
    - echo done
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - deploy.zip
```

Fails the build with the error:

> ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

My second (nth) try puts the robocopy into a script file and executes it from there:

(.gitlab-ci.yml)

```
before_script:
- S:\Storage\GitLab-Runner\Scripts\CopyAssets.bat
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo starting
    - gulp
    - echo done
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - deploy.zip
```

(CopyAssets.bat)

```
robocopy S:\Storage\GitLab-Runner\Assets\node_modules .\node_modules /s
set/A errlev="%ERRORLEVEL% & 24"
exit/B %errlev%
```

Passes but does not execute any other steps.

How can I prevent RoboCopy from exiting the build when it finishes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You and a lot of other people have encountered this issue with robocopy in CI deployment. As I have found this question being unanswered for some time and the other answers being incompatible with continuing the script after robocopy, I want to share the solution here.

If you want robocopy to ignore all return codes under 8 (>= 8 means copy error), you need a condition that follows the command directly and changes the error level.

```
(robocopy src dst) ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 8 SET ERRORLEVEL = 0
```

Comment: Successfully tested with Windows Server 2008 and gitlab-runner 10.4

Comment: It does not work for me. I get an error "Unexpected token '^' in expression or statement" using a docker image based on windows server core 2019.

Comment: The command is not powershell, but normal terminal / cmd

Comment: Keep in mind that successful copying returns exit code 1. Exit codes 2/4/8/10 are warnings/errors.

Answer (score 6):

For powershell users:

```
(robocopy src dst) ; if ($lastexitcode -lt 8) { $global:LASTEXITCODE = $null }
```

or

```
cmd /c (robocopy src dst) ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 1 exit 0
```

I have tested on GitLab 13.12 with GitLab Runner powershell and it worked well.